# I am not sure about this query

Tags: sql

query to extract the data from the customer table if and only if one or more of the customers in the customer table are located in London

and my query is

```
select * from Customer
where 'London' = ANY (select city from Customer)
```

I know it's not the correct way but I wanted to know if this also works or not.
TIA

Comment: Is this what you want? select * from Customer
where city='London'

Answer (score 2):

Your query works, so that is one way to express it (and rather clever).  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72ec71d3c14daa9a5469a76ca8a9895f) is an example.

More commonly, I think of this as an`exists` query:

```
select c.*
from Customer c
where exists (select 1 from Customer c2 where c2.city = 'London');
```

This will return all customers from any city, even those not in London.

It is quite possible that you just want to return customers in London, in which case a simple `where city = 'London'` suffices.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to coding hence wasn't sure if this makes any logic

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Customer where city ='London' and 1 > (select count(*) from Customer where city='London');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.